# Oscilloscope showed weird readings of a clipping circuit

Tags: diodes, oscilloscope, voltage-clipping

Circuit diagram (Vs is 10 Vpp sin wave at 1 kHz, and the oscilloscope was measuring Vo): [image: circuit diagram]

constructed circuit: [image: constructed circuit]

Here is the readings I got (noted that it was using AC coupling by accident): [image: oscilloscope graph]

The problem is that shouldn't the maximum voltage be 0.7 V when the AC coupling is using since it will remove DC component in the circuit which is the DC source in this case? Even if the AC coupling doesn't affect the readings, why does the maximum voltage isn't 2.5 V as 0.7 V + 1.8 V = 2.5 V?

The only possible reason I can think of is that the wire connections were incorrect, but I tried multiple combinations with simulation still cannot replicate the graph I got from the oscilloscope.

Comment: Please describe the 1.8V DC source. Many regulated DC supplies expect to be the sole source of current. Your circuit **supplies current** in pulses from the function generator through the diode to the DC supply. It is not clear how the DC supply responds to this unexpected current source. Have you actually measured +1.8V at the +ve terminal of that supply?

Comment: the 1.8 V is not the DC component in the output signal ... remove the 1.8 V supply and see what result you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that shouldn't the maximum voltage be 0.7V when the ac coupling is using since it will remove DC component in the circuit which is the DC source in this case?

The AC coupling setting removes the DC component of the *signal*, not the DC component of the *circuit*.

Basically, AC coupling shows you exactly the same thing that DC coupling would show you, except moved up or down so that the average value of the signal is at 0.

If you were using DC coupling, you'd see a signal with a minimum value of -5 V and a maximum value of 2.5 V (so the difference between the minimum and the maximum would be 7.5 V). Since you're using AC coupling, you see exactly the same thing, except that it's moved up a bit. In particular, the difference between the minimum and the maximum on the signal you see is still 7.5 V, exactly as we would expect.

Comment: so can i think of DC component of the signal is something that will move upward/downward the waveform which then makes the average voltage value become non-zero? By that, is that means I cant know directly it by looking at the circuit, instead, I have to look the the waveform?

Comment: @AlanHong To be precise, the DC component _is_ the average voltage (measured over a relatively long period of time, perhaps a second or more). If the average voltage is -2 V, then the DC component is -2 V; if the average voltage is 10 V, then the DC component is 10 V; if the average voltage is 0 V, then the DC component is 0 V. If the DC component is 0 V, we might say that there "is no DC component."

Comment: @AlanHong Looking at the waveform will definitely tell you what the DC component of the signal is; you may also be able to figure out the DC component by looking at the circuit, if the circuit is simple enough for you to be able to analyze it.

Comment: got it thank you!

Comment: one last question, is "average value", "DC component of signal", "DC level" and "DC offset" the same thing? @tannerswett

Comment: @AlanHong Pretty much, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Having the oscilloscope input set to AC coupling will set the vertical center of the waveform at zero volts *average*. The LTspice simulation of the circuit shows the waveforms with DC and AC coupling. 
The DC coupled waveform looks as it should with the clipping occurring at about 2.5 V and  average voltage equal to -529 mV.
The AC coupled waveform also looks as it should with the average voltage very near zero (within computational accuracy of the simulator).

For clipping circuits, DC coupling is normally the way to view the waveforms.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> *The problem is that shouldn't the maximum voltage be 0.7V when the ac
> coupling is using since it will remove DC component in the circuit
> which is the DC source in this case?*

The oscilloscope knows nothing about your circuit including the DC source used to offset the waveform; all AC coupling can do is ensure that the **average output voltage** is zero and, if you look at your image, it pretty much looks like that to me.

[image]

Or, put another way, area "A" equals area "B" in the above picture. And, if it weren't AC coupled then you would see a peak of around +2.5 volts.

Comment: May I have more information or resource to learn about this? "all AC coupling can do is ensure that the average output voltage is zero"

Comment: The purpose of AC coupling is to remove the DC component of a signal. The DC component is the average value of a periodic waveform. If your input is 1+sin(2pi*t), which has an average value of 1, the output of AC coupling will offset, removing the +1V DC

Comment: @YetAnotherMichael please address your comments i.e. if you intended that comment for me then address the comment `@andyaka`. This is to avoid confusion.

Comment: @AlanHong I can't provide a link to a resource on this or, put it another way, regard my answer as a resource but, if you don't understand something ask a specific question.